# After submit action in form_alter

Tags: drupal, hook-form-alter

i need to insert data in my tables after user creation. I think to use `hook_form_alter()` for `$form_id == "user_register"` but I don't know how to say "after you created user, do this."

How can I do it in `hook_form_alter()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add custom submit handler to forms like this.

```
function hook_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // ...
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourModule_user_register_submit';
}

function yourModule_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // do what you want to do after registration
}
```

I'd also recommend to use Drupal's [Triggers & Actions](http://drupal.org/node/199254#part-10) to achieve this. AFAIK there was a bug with one of the triggers that fire after user registration. Don't know if that has been fixed.